# Vlookup in a loop to copy information

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do a vlookup loop to search values in a list and return them in 4 specifics cells, but my formula its not working, its just returns the names of my variables in the cells.

```
    Private Sub copydata() 'copy fornecedor data if match

Dim rng As Range
Dim rang As Integer
Dim rang2 As Integer
Dim cell As Variant
Dim rang3 As Range


rang = Worksheets("Plan1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & rang)
Set rang3 = Range("Plan1!$G1:$K1000")

rang2 = 1


For Each cell In rng
rang2 = rang2 + 1
    If cell.Interior.Color = 65535 Then

   cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=vlookup(cell,rang3,2,0)"
   cell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=vlookup(cell,rang3,2,0)"
   cell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=vlookup(cell,rang3,2,0)"
   cell.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=vlookup(cell,rang3,2,0)"

    End If

Next cell
   End Sub
```

Comment: on a side note, I would just find the 1st row instance using match on cell, then index or offset to get the rest, no point looking up the value 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're putting the formula in, you cant use your variables, you need to write like `"=vlookup(" & cell.value & "," & rang3.address & ",2,0)"`

Also the forumula look up the same value, should you be incrementing the 2?

Comment: I'm trying to do what you said, but my formula is not recognizing the lookup value. Can you help me?

Comment: What is happening, without seeing the data, it's difficult to assist with a lookup :)  I'll do my best tho :)

Comment: Excel is giving me #NAME? and the cell is like this:
=PROCV(AERO DINAMICA EQUIPAMENTOS INDUSTRIAIS LTDA;$G$1:$K$1000;2;0)

My excel is in portuguese, so procv = vlookup and AERO DINAMICA EQUIPAMENTOS INDUSTRIAIS LTDA is the name that i'm looking for whit vlookup.

The error tells me that the formula could not recognize the text.

I hope you can help me with this information. Thank You!

Comment: Instead of "=vlookup(" & cell.value & "," & rang3.address & ",2,0)" i changed to "=vlookup(" & cell.Address & "," & rang3.address & ",2,0)"
 and worked.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is just a bit off. The variable ranges where buried in the quotes inside the VBA syntax. Since you want to return the variable elements you need to concatenate them together in such a way that the code will read the addresses for you.

This is one way to do it.

```
cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=vlookup(" & cell.address & "," & rang3.Parent & "!" & rang3.address & ",2,0)"
```

Comment: `rng3.Address(1,1,,True)` will put the parent in automatically.